# await statement not outputting message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having a bit of a conundrum with a line of my code which is not outputting a message.

How it should work

If lurker role is in member roles returns *I've found some lurkers ready to be kicked, would you like to kick them?*. - else if members with no lurker returns *No lurkers around to kick today.*

The issue I'm having is the message No lurkers around to kick today is not outputting.

Here is what I'm working with to give you an idea on what I'm trying to achieve:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def check_lurkers(self, ctx, *_):
    """Manually check for lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid) # Soon to change to ctx.message.server
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Lurker")
    member_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Members")
    any_lurkers = False
    for member in list(server.members):
        if member_role not in member.roles and lurker_role in member.roles:
            await self.bot.say("I've found some lurkers ready to be kicked, would you like to kick them?")
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for_message(timeout=10)
            if msg is None or msg.content.lower().strip() in ("no", "n"):
                await self.bot.say("No lurkers were kicked.")

            elif msg.content.lower().strip() in ("yes", "y"):
                await self.bot.kick(member)
                any_lurkers=True
            if any_lurkers:
                await self.bot.say("Adios lurkerinos! :wave:")
            else:
                await self.bot.say("No lurkers around to kick today. :raised_hands: ")
```

`else:
     await self.bot.say("No lurkers around to kick today. :raised_hands: ")`

This is the line that is not outputting anything. What am I doing wrong here?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your indentation?

Comment: Thats the thing I can't see where I'm going wrong with my indentation.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you should instead build a list of "lurkers", then ask the user if they should be kicked, then loop through that list to kick them.  Or should the process ask on a per-lurker basis?  If so, you should probably send the lurkers name to the person making the decision.

Comment: Hey @PatrickHaugh How I'm trying to do this is if the command is `!check_lurkers` and say a member has the lurker role it returns the found lurkers message which prompts whether they should be kicked from the server,  else if no members have the lurkers role then it should return the no lurkers found message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we build a list of lurkers, then decide whether or not to kick them.  Notice that the decision to kick or not happens exactly once, outside of a loop.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
@checks.is_owner()
async def check_lurkers(self, ctx):
    """Manually check for lurkers"""

    serverid = '465536300452151298'
    server = self.bot.get_server(serverid) # Soon to change to ctx.message.server
    lurker_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Lurker")
    member_role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="Members")
    any_lurkers = False
    lurkers = [member for member in server.members 
               if member_role not in member.roles and lurker_role in member.roles]
    if lurkers:
        await self.bot.say("I've found some lurkers ready to be kicked, would you like to kick them?")
        msg = await self.bot.wait_for_message(timeout=10)
        if msg is None or msg.content.lower().strip() not in in ("yes", "y"):
            await self.bot.say("No lurkers were kicked.")
        else:
            for lurker in lurkers:
                await self.bot.kick(lurker)
            await self.bot.say("Adios lurkerinos! :wave:")
    else:
        await self.bot.say("No lurkers around to kick today. :raised_hands: ")
```